# Is there a way to display column relationships with a third column?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have these tables in a database:

fish (id, f.name, image, cooking_type_id)

cooking_type (id, name, thumbnail)

If I display a list of all the fishes, how do I display the correct thumbnails for type_id?

I'm having troubles finding the right information. Right now I'm stuck with this query:

```
$query = "SELECT `f.name`, `image`, `type_id`
            FROM fish";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
        echo '<div class="row" style="background-color:#fff;">';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="listphoto">';
        echo $row['image'];
        echo '</div></div>';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="listtext"><h3>';
        echo $row['f.name'];
        echo '</a></h3></div></div>';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<div class="typethumbnail">';
        echo '';
        echo '</div></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this query.

```
 SELECT f.name, f.image, c.thumbnail
   FROM fish f
   JOIN cooking_type c ON f.cooking_type_id = c.id
```

You use the the `ON` clause in your `JOIN` operation to express how the rows of `fish` relate to the rows of `cooking_type`.

If you have multiple tables, you can use a series of JOIN operations to relate them. For example:

```
 SELECT f.name, f.image, c.thumbnail, m.market_name, m.price, p.pan_type
   FROM fish f
   JOIN cooking_type c ON f.cooking_type_id = c.id
   JOIN fishmarket m ON f.name = m.species_name
   JOIN pan p ON c.name = p.cooking_type_name
```

Comment: Is it possible to use JOIN on more than 1 column? If I have a table where I want to display 3 relational tables?

Comment: Yes. Please see my edit. You should study up on JOIN operations; they're the conceptual heart of database systems.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I read a couple of short JOIN tutorials right after your first answer but this short comment opened up a whole new world for me. Can I award you for this answer somehow?